# Check to see if a control is locked - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, combobox, textbox, vba

I am trying to loop through all of my controls on a single multipage.  If a control is locked, I don't want anything to happen to it.  if it isn't locked, it's content is to be cleared.  I used the following technique in the past, but it won't be effective this time around.

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Value).Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then ctl.Value = ""
Next
```

I know I can check single items and do the following...

```
If TextBox1.Locked = True Then
    //Set value to ""
End If
```

That wouldn't do the trick either as I have a lot of input's on this page.  Any thoughts as to how I can modify my original technique to accomplish this task?

Comment: why do you think `If ctl.locked Then ...` will not work for you?

Comment: @DavidZemens I tried doing that and I was getting an error.  So far, I tried adding Dim ctl As Textbox, and I'm now getting a type mixmatch error.

Comment: OK. Probably error arises because some form controls do not have a `.Locked` property?  Let me suggest a revision to your logic. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Just break out your logic a bit more to handle the nuances of different control types.  If this also raises an error, let me know which line raises the error and what is the error message.

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Value).Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctl) 
        Case "TextBox" 
            If Not ctl.Locked Then ctl.Value = ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            ctl.Value = ""
        Case Else
            'ignore other controls, or modify as necessary
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: That worked out perfectly.  I wasn't thinking about putting it through a case test.

Comment: You could have done it with nested `If` statements, too, but I generally prefer `Case` statements for ease of readability.